# I have a zip folder which contains 332 csv file. I have to first unzip it using R and then save it to a directory. How do i do that?

Tags: r

I have tried-
`read.zip(file ="C:/Users/dm/Downloads/rprog-data-specdata.zip")`

and-
`l = list.files("C:/Users/dm/Downloads/rprog-data-specdata")
read.csv(l[1:332])`

But it's not working

Answer (score 4):

Unless you really want them all extracted, you don't have to. You can read them all in directly from the archive:

```
# you 
zipped_csvs <- "rprog-data-specdata.zip"

# get data.frame of file info in the zip
fils <- unzip(zipped_csvs, list=TRUE)

# read them all into a list (or you can read individual ones)
dats <- lapply(fils$Name, function(x) {
  read.csv(unzip(zipped_csvs, x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})
```